# Why does "git status" not show an existing commit?

Tags: git

I created a branch:

```
git checkout -b FRANK...
```

I edited files and commited them:

```
git commit .
```

I attempted to undo these commits:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

And now I don't understand what I'm seeing from git status.

git diff origin

gives me changes which I do not see with

```
git status
```

How can I return to normal behavior?

```
user@hostname:/src$ git status
On branch FRANK_04_14_2020_SET_INPUT_SCOPE_LOOPS
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   astBase.cpp
    modified:   astBase.h
    modified:   constantPropagation.cpp
    modified:   setInputScope.cpp
user@hostname:/src$ git diff origin NewSdiWriter.cpp
    ...non-empty....
user@hostname:/src$
```

After some comments:

One more reason so abandon git.

I took the easy way out:

- create a patch of the changes
- go back to master
- create a new branch and switch to it
- apply the patch

In my universe git status is (usually) also showing how many commits have been done without a push:

```
hostName /dirName : git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
hostName /dirName :
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're expecting to see. "git status" shows changes in the working directory compared to *the currently checked out commit*. "origin" normally refers to a remote copy of the repository somewhere; I'm not even sure what that means as an argument on its own to "git diff", but it's certainly not "currently checked out commit"

Comment: so how do I refer to what usually is "origin"? I've used "origin" since years. So your saying origin is something different when I'm working inside a branch?

Comment: but "origin" refers to the root of this branch -- there is no difference. So "origin" is correct. Why would status not show anything.

Comment: @FrankPuck `git diff origin` is *indeed* a very strange command. What do you expect it to ouput? `origin` is the default name for the remote from which the repo was cloned, **not** a branch.

Comment: I'm not asking about git diff origin -- I'm getting what I expect from it.

I'm asking about git status.It does not show me what I expected to see.

Comment: @FrankPuck You may not be asking about "git diff origin", but we are. I've no idea what it shows, and why you expect it to be the same as "git status". Note that in git there isn't really a concept of "the root of a branch"; branch names are just pointers to the _tip_ of a particular branch, and from there to a sequence of commits right back to the beginning of the repository.

Comment: The command to show uncommitted changes in a particular file would just be "git diff NewSdiWriter.cpp". Those are the changes that "git status" is listing. I don't know what you were expecting to see.

Comment: Exactly what changes are you not seeing?  The output of git status you show looks perfectly normal; it doesn't show changes, it just shows which files have changed.  If you added any new files in the commit that you made, they will not show up because those files don't exist in the current HEAD.

Comment: `git diff origin` will show a diff between the current working directory and the ref `refs/remotes/origin` or `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  See `man git-rev-parse` for details.

Answer (score 1):

To start off with, let's look at what various pointers referenced in your scenario:

- When you started, you had a particular commit checked out, let's call it "A"
- You created a branch, I'll call it "FRANK" for short, pointing at commit "A", and made it the current working branch ("HEAD")
- You made some changes, and committed them; this created a commit we'll call "B", and moved the "FRANK" pointer to that commit

Then you ran `git reset HEAD~1`, which did the following:

- The "FRANK" pointer moved back to commit A
- The "HEAD" pointer was still a reference to "FRANK", so the currently checked out commit was commit A
- Your *working copy* contained the files you'd changed in commit B
- Commit B was "orphaned" - if you don't point something else at it, it will eventually get "garbage collected" because nothing references it any more

Through all of this, "origin" didn't change. That refers to the state of some remote repository, affected by fetch, pull, and push commands.

The "ahead/behind" line at the top of "git status" compares the currently checked out branch against *the branch on a remote server that it tracks*:

- According to your description, you never pushed or pulled branch "FRANK", so it will never have shown anything.
- If you ran "git push" immediately after creating the branch, the remote branch would point at commit A. So after creating commit "B", it would show "1 commit ahead" - commit B is 1 ahead of commit A.
- Once you reset back to commit A again, it would show as even with the remote branch - both point at commit A. It's only measuring commits, so your uncommitted changes are irrelevant.

The main body of "git status" shows uncommitted changes in the working copy. As mentioned above, "git reset" left all the changes in the working copy, so they'd all be listed.

"git diff origin NewSdiWriter.cpp" is a peculiar command.

- "origin" is the name of the default "remote" - git's name for a link to a repository on another server. Normally, you would reference *a particular branch* of a remote repository, but just "origin" on its own where git expects a commit will refer to the current commit of the default branch of that repository ("refs/remotes/origin/HEAD" as [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) pointed out).
- Without a second argument, "git diff" compares against the current working copy. That doesn't mean it will show only uncommitted changes, it will show everything that's different between its argument and what's in your current checked out state.
- So in this case whatever the code looks like on the default branch of the origin remote will be compared against your working copy. Note that git won't talk to the remote server automatically, so it will compare against its local cache from last time you ran "git fetch" or "git pull".

Presumably, the file NewSdiWriter.cpp is different on that branch and your current commit, because you or someone else has edited it; but that change is already committed somewhere, so won't show in "git status".

Some more useful commands to see where you're actually at:

- `git diff NewSdiWriter.cpp` - shows the uncommitted changes to the file "NewSdiWriter.cpp"
- `git diff --staged NewSdiWriter.cpp` - shows changes "staged" to be included in the next commit
- `git log` with various options - show the history of the current branch to see what you've committed
- `git diff origin/main HEAD` - compares a particular remote branch (in your local cache) against the currently checked out commit

Comment: I don't think "origin" refers to the remote, because if it would, it would be affected by changes to the remote by other people. This is definitely not the case!

Comment: You missed to explain, why git status did not show the changes to NewSdiWriter.cpp.

Comment: @FrankPuck 1) "origin" is the name of the default remote. Maybe you have something else called "origin", I can't possibly know, but that's 100% what it means on most people's working copies. 2) git status didn't show any changes to NewSdiWriter.cpp because none were uncommitted. It doesn't care about your "origin", whatever that turns out to actually mean, so there's absolutely no reason to assume it will match the output of "git diff origin".

Comment: @FrankPuck: More precisely, `origin` is indeed the name of a *remote* (normally, and presumably true here as well because, well, `ahead of 'origin/master'`). But wait! The name of a remote *is* usable as a commit-specifier via [the documented rules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), specifically step 6 of the six numbered steps just a page or so into the documentation.